# Spring WebClient deserialize json to generic types

Tags: java, spring

I have a rest api which return response like below:

```
{
   code : '00000', 
   total: 2
   data : [
      {},
      {},
   ]
}
```

the data is an array of type depends on uri. for example, if uri is `/user`

```
{
   code : '00000', 
   total: 2 
   data : [
      {"username" : "jack", email: "jack@acme.com"},
      {"username" : "rose", email: "rose@acme.com"}
   ]
}
```

if uri is `/task`, then response will be

```
    {
       code : '00000',
       total: 2 
       data : [
          {"id" : 1, name: "clean house"},
          {"id" : 2, name: "buy food"}
       ]
    }
```

my java model to represent such response:

```
public class SEAReadResponse<T> extends SEAResponse {
    
    private long total;
    
    private List<T> data;

    public long getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(long total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public List<T> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
}
```

now calling such api with spring's WebClient:

```
public class HttpRestSEAClient implements ISEAClient {
    
    private WebClient client;
    
    public HttpRestSEAClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        client = builder.build();
    }

    public <T> List<T> read(SEAReadRequest<T> req) {
        ParameterizedTypeReference<SEAReadResponse<T>> typeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<SEAReadResponse<T>>() {};
        return client.put().uri(req.getLocator()).bodyValue(req).retrieve().bodyToMono(typeReference).block().getData();
    }

}
```

```
SEAReadRequest<User> userReq = new SEAReadRequest<User>();
userReq.setLocator("pub/user");
userReq.setFilter(in("userId", userIds.keySet()));
userReq.setIncludes(new String[] {"userId", "userName"});
client.read(userReq).forEach(u -> {
    userIds.put(u.getUserId(), u.getUserName());
});
```

an CCE was thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to fwx.apps.pub.models.User
```

please help.